# Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment - asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the above error. It is working in Dev mode but not on live, any ideas?

There are proper values in the reader as I've written them to a text file....

```
        Do While reader.Read()
            personList.Add(New Person() With {.ID = reader("user_id"), .Name = reader("person")})
        Loop
```

Thanks,

```
Public Class Person
Private m_ID As Integer
Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_ID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_ID = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Name As String
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_Name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Can we see the Person class? At least the properties.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76435b93(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted now, just did it a different way. Got the new constructor to take parameters and set them that way. Put them as optional as construct being called somewhere else and params not needed.

```
Public Sub New(Optional ByVal uid As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal uname As String = "")
    ID = uid
    Name = uname
End Sub


Dim uid As Integer
Dim uname As String
Do While reader.Read()
   uid = reader("user_id")
   uname = reader("person")
   personList.Add(New Person(uid, uname))
Loop
```